# Firebase populates chat list with only one element

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this ChatRoom application [here](https://albatross-e29fd.firebaseapp.com/) built referring "Friendlychat-web". The problem is only the most recent item in the Realtime database is being populated.

the gist of the code can be found here: [main.js](https://gist.github.com/rakhi2104/3c3d52f8dc1a92fbf330d188cada0f17)

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("messages");

function loadMessages() {
  document.getElementById("messages-list").innerHTML = "";
  query.on("value", async snapshot => {
    if (snapshot.val()) {
      await Object.keys(snapshot.val()).forEach(async key => {
        document.getElementById("messages-list").innerHTML += generateMessage(await snapshot.val()[key]);
      });

    } else {
      document.getElementById("messages-list").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById(
        "messages-list"
      ).innerHTML += `<li class="center"> No Messages yet</li>`;
    }
  });
}


function authStateObserver(user) {
  loadRoomMembers();
  loadMessages();
  if(user){ /*... action ...*/}
}
```

The chat functionality works fine until you refresh.

Before refresh:
[image: before refresh]

After refresh:
[image: after refresh]

Comment: As I see it, it should work but if your save message function is broken and replace the message instead of adding it to a list, you'll have this comportement. Maybe try to aggregate the result of you forEach into a string, and replacing the innerHtml totally with it each time. You'll see if it is a issue with writing or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in itself looks like it should work. But the way you loop over the messages is non-idiomatic, so it's hard to spot error in there. A better way to loop over the results is to use `Snapshot.forEach()` like this:

```
function loadMessages() {
  query.on("value", snapshot => {
    let list = document.getElementById("messages-list");
    if (snapshot.val()) {
      list.innerHTML = "";
      snapshot.forEach(messageSnap => {
        list.innerHTML += generateMessage(messageSnap.val());
      });
    } else {
      list.innerHTML += `<li class="center"> No Messages yet</li>`;
    }
  });
}
```

Note that I also removed the `async` and `await`, since your code seems to not need it and it just introduces more room for error.